# Adding & subtracting variable id into a new hidden form element

Tags: jquery, variables, clone, addition, subtraction

I'm a noob and need help with my jQuery/javascript code. Currently, I have functions that when a div containing a specific class (.add) is clicked, the child image of that div is cloned into another renamed, cloned div (#theDiv) within a container (#hold). The user can then click on the cloned divs within the second container (#hold) which will then delete that div and it's contents. Hopefully that's not too hard to understand!

I would now like to include a hidden form element with specific ID requirements inside each cloned div, along with the child image. The tricky part is that the ID within the hidden form element must include a unique identifying number, starting with zero. The current function allows the user to clone up to six divs which would mean the ID variable number would never go past a value of 5. when the user clicks to delete a div within the "hold" container, and then clones another, logic needs to be in place to prevent the ID variable number to continue on past the value of five.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- User clicked on one of these to clone -->
<div class="add"><img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2u5yg6g.png"></div>
<div class="add"><img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2u5yg6g.png"></div>
<div class="add"><img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2u5yg6g.png"></div>

<!-- theDiv is cloned with contents, renamed and child image is cloned within the new div container  -->
<div id="hold">
    <div id="theDiv" style="display:none;" class="myClass">
       <div class="deletehover delete">Delete</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.textI').each(function() {
var default_value = this.value;
$(this).focus(function() {
    if(this.value == default_value) {
        this.value = '';
    }
});

});

function theDiv_append() {
var $hold = $('#hold'),
    len = $hold.children('div').length;

if (len <= 6) {
var clone = $('#theDiv')
              .clone()
              .attr('id','')
              .show()
              .append(
                  $('<div>').html(
                      $(this).children('img').clone()
                  ).addClass('packimage delete')
              );
$('#hold').append(clone)
} else {
    alert('You have already selected a full pack of photos.');
}
}
$(document).on('click', '.add', theDiv_append);

$(function(){  
  $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
});

});//]]>
```

**Hidden form field ID where "#" should equal a unique value ranging from 0-5:**

```
textField#
```

**Example hidden field with id of the first cloned div set:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="textField0" name="custom_name" value="custom_value">
```

**JSfiddle of current working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sstracy/GMs7k/2/**

Any help solving this would be AMAZING! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out on my own with a rather simple answer to my own question after a great deal of thought. I'll post my answer out of the benefit of the community.

Since it becomes rather complicated to figure out which IDs might be available after a user deletes any of the clones they want, the code simply resets all the ID values each time the user clicks to create a new clone.

So first I appended a hidden input field without any ID:

```
.append('<input type="hidden">');
```

Then after the cloned DIV with the child image and now the hidden input is created, I count all the child input fields within my container "#hold" and assign them a new ID which includes jQuery's built-in numerical "index" function, starting with zero. If the hidden input field already has an ID value, it is overwritten with a new one:

```
$("#hold input").each(function(index) {
     $(this).attr("id", "textField" + index);
});
```

I added an example to Fiddle with text fields so you can see when the values given: http://jsfiddle.net/M82pG/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just add it

Since you say you cannot use Len, create an IDX var and use id="textfield'+(IDX++)+'">' like this

```
$('<div>')
  .html($(this).children('img').clone())
  .append('<input type="hidden" id="textfield'+IDX+'">')
  .addClass('packimage delete')
```

Comment: It's a start and thanks for replying but I foresee two issues with this. I believe the 'len' value will always be one numeric value too high, since I need to start at 0. 2: If you add four clones, delete one and then add another, you end up with two hidden input fields with the same ID.

Comment: So create an IDX var and use `id="textfield'+(IDX++)+'">'` but if you delete the clone, you delete the parent so that removes the hidden field too so you can use (len-1) if it needs to be one less. Lastly `var IDX = $('#theDiv').find("input").length-1;`

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. That would work if only the last clone created was also being delete but that is not always true as you can see from the JSfiddle, you can delete any of the clones. Simply counting wont guarantee the same ID will not be created again.